# IdentityServer v3 and custom cookies

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, identityserver3

I'm updating our MVC application to use IdentityServer v3 to implement OpenID Connect authentication using implicit flow.

I've overridden the IdentityServer `AuthenticateLocalAsync` method of the `UserServiceBase` class to call into our existing authentication service to validate the supplied credentials. This service also sets various cookies required by our application.

The issue I'm encountering is that upon entering the credentials in the login page, it doesn't redirect to the `ReturnUri` specified in the `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions` parameter of `UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication` method. Instead it remains on the login page and appears to go into an infinite loop, alternating between calls to the notification handlers `SecurityTokenValidated` and `SecurityTokenReceived`. There is no indication of any error in the IdentityServer logs.

I think the cause of the issue is related to setting the application-specific cookies in our authentication service. If I comment out the following, it then successfully redirects upon logging in:

```
var cookie = new HttpCookie("AppCookie") { HttpOnly = false, Secure = true };
cookie ["CustomField1"] = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(customValue1);
cookie ["CustomField2"] = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(customValue2);
this._httpContext.Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);
```

However these cookies are required by our application and so need to be set in the response. Why would setting these cookies prevent it from redirecting? Are there any workarounds? Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Two questions, Is your MVC application embeded in your IdentityServer3 app? Is your MVC application built on top of [Katana](https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/)?

Comment: @Ming Yes they are both part of the same application and built on top of Katana.

Comment: I would suggest to set cookie using OwinResponse.Cookies property instead of HttpContext.Response.Cookie. It doesn't guarantee to fix your issue but worth to try

Comment: also why u use 'set' instead of 'add'? Is 'AppCookie' also the client authentication cookie?

Comment: Thanks @Ming. Using `OwinResponse.Cookies` resolved the issue. `AppCookie` isn't related to authentication. I'm not sure why it uses `set` instead of `add` (I didn't implement it). Perhaps it was to prevent duplicate cookies.

Comment: nice!  i should have post it as an answer :)